# How to scale objects and tiles without doubling view port in gamemaker

Tags: game-maker

How do I scale up tiles and sprites without acully making the view port larger than the acual view? I know that I can just scale up the images and the tileset but there must better alternative right? The reason why I dont want to make the port bigger is because then I get this kind of "pixel perfect" behaviour so 1 pixel on the image is one pixel on the screen (So it looks kind of choppy). I'm thinking I can use the draw event if there's no other alternative but how would I do that with the tileset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how you want to scale them up. You can scale objects when you're placing them in Rooms by just dragging out their corners (and maybe holding Shift to keep them evenly scaled). You *might* be able to do the same with tiles.

Otherwise, if you're looking to scale sprites in real time in the game, you can use the function [draw_sprite_ext](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/drawing/drawing%20sprites%20and%20backgrounds/draw_sprite_ext.html), and to scale tiles you can use [tile_set_scale](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/game%20assets/backgrounds/background%20tiles/tile_set_scale.html).